# When is it appropriate to use CacheItemRemovedCallback?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a large data set that is updated once a day. I am caching the results of an expensive query on that data but I want to update that cache each day. I am considering using CacheItemRemovedCallback to reload my cache on a daily interval, but I had the following concerns:

1. Isn't it possible that the CacheItemRemovedCallback could be called before my expiration (in the case of running out of memory)? Which means reloading it immediately doesn't seem like a good idea.
2. Does the CacheItemRemovedCallback get called before or after the item is actually removed? If it is after, doesn't this theoretically leave a period of time where the cache would be unavailable?

Are these concerns relevant and if using CacheItemRemovedCallback to reload your cache is a bad idea, then when is it useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From everyone's responses and from further reading I have come to the following conclusion:

My concerns are valid. Using CacheItemRemovedCallback to refresh cached items is not a good idea. The only practical use for this callback seems to be logging information about when your cache is removed.

It seems that CacheItemUpdateCallback is the more appropriate way of refreshing your cache on a regular interval.

Ultimately, I have decided not to use either of these calls. Instead I will write a service action so the database import job can notify my application when it needs to refresh its data. This avoids using a timed refresh altogether.

Comment: Well, there are other practical uses for `CacheItemRemovedCallback` - not just logging. Say for instance that there are external references kept by a cached item that you want to dispose of when the cached item is removed. If you do not use CacheItemRemovedCallback you would then have to rely solely on the Garbage Collector which provides no guarantee when it will execute (if ever during the life of your program).

Answer (score 4):

1. If you're going to reload, be sure to check the CacheItemRemovedReason. I recently had to debug an issue where a developer decided they should immediately re-populate the cache in this method, and under low memory conditions, it basically sat chewing up CPU while it got stuck in a loop of building the cache objects, adding them to the cache, expiring, repeat.
2. The callback is fired **after** the item is removed.

Comment: "Very helpful!"

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, there is a change that the method could be fired off for a lot of various reasons. However, loading or waiting to load the cache again would be dependent upon what is best for your typical use case in your application.
2. CacheItemRemovedCallback does indeed fire *after* the item is removed from the cache. Right *before* the item is to be removed, you can use the CacheItemUpateCallback method to determine whether or not you want to flush the cache at that time. There may be good reasons to wait in flushing the cache, such as you currently have users in your application and it takes a long amount of time to build the cache again.

Generally speaking, the best practice is to test that your cached item actually exists in the cache before using its data. If the data doesn't exist, you can rebuild the cache at that time (causing a slightly longer response for the user) or choose to do something else.

Answer (score 1):

This really isn't so much a cache of individual values as it is a snapshot of an entire dataset. As such, you don't benefit from using the `Cache` class here.

I'd recommend loading a static collection on startup and replacing it every 24 hours by setting a timer. The idea would be to create a new collection and atomically assign it, as the old one may still be in use and we want it to remain self-consistent.